# UI Controls for ASP.NET MVC, GridViews, Calendars and more

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc

How come there are a lack of Controls for ASP.NET MVC?

Sure it hasn't been around that long but one would think that a GridView, Calendar and other important controls would be *included* or at least in seperate packages.

However, I've failed to find any besides the ones that cost a lot of money for nearly nothing at all.

Does these type of controls go against the work-flow in MVC?

**Edit**

Regarding the specific controls, the jQuery Calendar seems very good however, I haven't seen any [hierchy grid-views](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/hierarchy/nestedviewtemplate/defaultcs.aspx) yet, are there any?

Comment: What aspects of the gridview and calendar do you need? Databinding? Sorting? Exactly what do you need the controls to do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since ASP.NET MVC doesn't have the same client/server abstraction as regular ASP.NET, you use regular client-side controls (ie HTML/Javascript). There are numerous frameworks available for complex reusable controls. I'd recommend JQuery/JQuery UI, but there is also Yahoo's framework (YUI), ExtJS, etc.

Comment: What are you referring to?  MVC has an even MORE pronounced client server abstraction.  The client happens to be the view, while the model on controller reside on teh server.

Comment: I'm referring to server controls - Viewstate, etc.

Answer (score 4):

There's www.jquery.com, www.coolite.com (with MVC support, based on Ext JS) and www.extjs.com.

The Telerik extensions for MVC are free and open-source, based on jQuery. Available at http://www.telerik.com/products/aspnet-mvc.aspx.

Comment: Do you know if there is a GridView which allowes you to bind Sub-lists to each element which are displayed as a second, inlined, table?

Comment: Try finding jqGrid. ExtJS also supports this.

Comment: I would not recommend teletrik it has some bugs and it is difficult to adopt in CSS

Answer (score 3):

Do you mean controls released by Microsoft?

You can always use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) or [ExtJs](http://www.extjs.com/) and I think [Telerik](http://www.telerik.com/) has some MVC controls.

Comment: Telerik costs a lot of money. Does jQuery have a nice GridView?

Comment: The MVC controls from Telerik are free and there are several grid controls based on jQuery. don't know if ExtJs is based on jQuery or not.

Answer (score 3):

A Control is a concept in ASP.NET that does not exist as such in ASP.NET MVC.

You may achieve a similar degree of feature isolation with ASP.NET MVC Areas, something I haven't looked at yet.

**Update:** If you downvote, explain why. And then show me where Controls are in ASP.NET MVC. Thanks!

Comment: I upvoted because you are right.  You should use Html (or HtmlHelpers for readability and maintainability).

Comment: I think you missunderstood the term "Control". The topic might be a bit unclear, but this is definitely not the answer i was looking for. Thanks anyways

Answer (score 2):

Check this for jQuery grid

http://trirand.com/jqgrid/jqgrid.html

Answer (score 1):

I would say the simple answer is that MVC simply doesn't need controls.  I've used a few of the [MVC Contrib](http://www.codeplex.com/MVCContrib) extensions, but for the most part you're just writing plain old html.  Which is what any control is going to do in the background.

Instead of a gridview I use a plain table, and if I need a calender I just use the jQuery one.

Answer (score 1):

ASP.NET MVC implies using some hacks to achieve such essential behavior. The main idea is to move part of page rendering logic to client JavaScript code. This is OK for relatively wide variety of simple web-sites.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't been to impressed with the selections myself. Take a look at Telerik for instance. Telerik MVC controls are somewhat lacking compared to Telerik's ASP.NET AJAX controls, and the MVC controls they do have are pale in comparison to the ASP.NET AJAX equivalent.

I have found the following so far:

> http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/ (free!)
>
> http://www.componentart.com/products/aspnetmvc/
>
> http://www.syncfusion.com/products/user-interface-edition/aspnet-mvc
>
> http://www.componentone.com/SuperProducts/StudioMVCWijmo/